# Transforming json with keys:values to column name:rows df using pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a json string that contain data likes this:

```
{"key1":"1","key2":2,"key 3":"text3",
 "key4":{"subkey4.1":"text4.1","subkey4.2":"date"},
 "key5":[{"subkey5.1":"text5.1","subkey5.2":"text5.2"}],"key6":"6"}
```

I would like to transform into pandas df, using keys as column names, subkeys as secondary columns, and key values as separate rows under the respective column.

Guessing pivot function needs to be used but not sure how.

this is a snippet of an actual string (removed long names and https for brevity): https://trinket.io/python/8e989e4d04

Comment: Is the one-element list by "key5" intentional? Why is there no list by "key4"?

Comment: yes, it's intentional, the source string is very long and contains dozens of keys, I just used the types of keys in this example.

Comment: Does the list always have one dictionary?

Comment: looking at the entire string there seems to be a number of dictionaries within it, I added a snippet of the actual string for reference.

Comment: The snipped that you added is not a legal Python expression.

Comment: Could I probably simplify this by pulling the data for certain type of variables and converting them to df and then joining the dfs together?

Comment: would it help if I paste the whole thing? it's a bit long though.